# Some PDF files get Forbidden Access and other open normally on the same directory subsites

Tags: multisite, htaccess, 404-error

I have a WordPress multi-site with 4 subdomains. 
All PDFs in the main domain site work fine while on subdomain I get Forbidden access for certain PDFs. For instance when I open:

```
http://example.com/pres/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/doc1-2016.pdf
```

it opens normally, but when I open

```
http://example.com/pres/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/doc222-2020.pdf
```

I get:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 403

here the .htaccess codes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I disabled all plugins but it still does not work.

I put `.htaccess` to allow PDF files but does not work.

what should I do now?

Comment: Are the file permissions of these files the same? How exactly did you "put `.htaccess` to allow PDF files"?

Comment: Have you spoken with your hosting provider?

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Comment: @MrWhite yes both files are the same permissions, even the new uploades get access forbidden too,

I put a .htaccess file include Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(pdf|csv|doc|docx|jpe?g|png|gif|ppt|pptx)$">
Allow from all
</Files>

but doesnot work

Comment: @TomJNowell I am the server owner windows server II with apache server insalled xammp

Comment: That `.htaccess` snippet would have blocked access to a lot of essential files and broken your site?! Try (temporarily) removing the `.htaccess` file completely - are these PDF files still not accessible? If not then it would seem to be something with your server config and not WordPress related?

Comment: Also what did you change in the HTAccess? Can you include it in your question?

Comment: thanks @MrWhite for your answer unfortunately i removed all the htaccess on the wp-content folder and still not working, what to look for in the server config about that issue?

Comment: @TomJNowell  here the htaccess in the main wordpress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: when i removed the htaccess on the main wordpress file i got the following


 The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

Comment: Yes, if you remove the `.htaccess` file you will get 404s if you are using "pretty" permalinks (the `.htaccess` file is essential for "pretty" permalinks to work). However, it also rules out that WordPress might be interfering with the serving of your PDFs. Can you access these troublesome PDFs via FTP OK? Any code updates should be edited into your question, not written in a comment. Apart from being a "mess", unformatted comments can also "hide" certain characters that make the code _impossible_ to read.

Comment: @Koa can you edit your question instead of posting code in comments? The comments mangle code

Comment: I added the htaccess lines in the question.

Yes I can open the troublesome pdfs normally